# Created New DataFrame Column, Unsigned Mininmum Less Than Zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm very new to using Pandas DataFrames and was seeking help on creating a new column which is the unsigned minimum less than zero of an exiting column, something like...

```
df["B"] = abs(min(0, df["A"]))
```

...in other words, if `A` is greater than `0` then `B` equals `0`,
otherwise `B` equals `-A`

Answer (score 1):

Use [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```py
df['B'] =  df.apply(lambda x:x['B'] if x['A'] > 0 else -x['A'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is how your data looks like

```
+---+-----+
|   |  A  |
+---+-----+
| 0 | -10 |
| 1 |  20 |
| 2 |  50 |
| 3 | -25 |
| 4 |   8 |
+---+-----+
```

```
import numpy as np
```

```
df['B'] = np.where(df['A'] > 0, 0,-df['A'])
```

This will give the following result

```
+---+-----+----+
|   |  A  | B  |
+---+-----+----+
| 0 | -10 | 10 |
| 1 |  20 |  0 |
| 2 |  50 |  0 |
| 3 | -25 | 25 |
| 4 |   8 |  0 |
+---+-----+----+
```